# Why is CASPol allowing my .NET application to run?

Tags: c#, security

Curious to know why my 2.0 .net application is being allowed to execute when I have restricted the permissions assigned to the assembly.

I've created a new Code Group at the Enterprise level which will match for any assembly with a particular digital signature.  The code group has been set so that only permissions from the associated permission set will be used and also that lower policy levels will not be evaluated.

Running the .Net 2.0 PermCalc states that my application needs the following permissions:

- UnmanagedCode,
- Environment
- FileIO
- Registry
- Reflection

I've assigned to my custom code group the permission for unmanaged code but nothing else.

The first method in my application demands all of the above permissions upfront so I can display a sensible message to the user before exiting.

Running the .NET 2.0 Configuation "Evaluate Assembly" tool on my assembly indeed shows that my application will only be given the UnmanagedCode permission.

However when I execute my application is runs and completes, quite obviously doing various FileIO and Registry operations.

My app is signed with the digital signature that should match the restricted code group.

Can anyone explain why this works.

**Note:** My ultimate aim is to make sure that my application does not crash horribly if executed from a network share.  I would have liked to check the assembly evidence zone is My_Computer but I can no longer do that with .NET 3.5 SP1. See [FullTrust On the LocalIntranet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/12/fulltrust-on-the-localintranet.aspx)

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured your CAS policy correctly, then chances are that your application isn't being denied the permissions you expect because it is not being run under the CLR whose policy you configured.  Do you perhaps have 32-bit and 64-bit CLRs installed on the same machine?

Another possibility might be that your "early check" demand is in the wrong place.  Is it directly in your application's Main method?  If so, when the demand runs, there won't be any of your application code on the call stack that is verified.  If this is the problem, simply moving the demand into another method invoked from Main should allow the demand to fail.

Comment: Hi Nicole,  Thanks for your response.  I've realise I made a mistake in my question which is misleading. My application is actually a .Net 2.0 application (and shouldn't have a prerequisites of 3.5).  I do actually have 3.5 SP1 Framework installed however.  I need to make this check since users might only have .NET 2.0 installed but still try to execute from a network share.  In this case, the app just crashes and I would like it to be more graceful.  The scenario outlined above was a test situation where I expected my application to crash.... but it does not!

Comment: I'll double check about the 32/64 bit clr now.

Comment: Ah...  Makes much more sense now.  I've edited my answer to add another possible explanation for the demand passing under the stated conditions.

Comment: Yes my checks are the first think my app does in its static main method entry point.  I have a list of permission.Demand() calls, one for each of the permissions that permcalc.exe stated I would need.

Comment: It does seem that the .NET 2.0 configuration tool I was using was editing the 32 bit Framework, not the 64 bit one.  I'm going to try to use the caspol.exe commandline tool in the Framework64 folder to see if I can reduce my applications permission set.

Answer (score -1):

you can still check the assembly evidence zone in .NET 3.5 SP1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.policy.zone.aspx.

For what caspol allows your assembly see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1dts55.aspx.

This http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2007/10/26/adhoc-poll-allowing-net-exes-to-run-off-a-network-share.aspx could affect what you see...

**EDIT:**

For checking when running from a network share you can still get `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and then check whether it a UNC or netowrk drive via `DriveType` for your location `System.IO.DriveInfo[]` (i.e. System.IO.DriveType.Network).

Comment: With .NET 3.5 SP1 managed applications running from a network share are shown to by in the MY_COMPUTER_ZONE instead of the INTRANET_ZONE.  This means I can no longer check if my app is executing in the MY_COMPUTER_ZONE because it could potentially still be on a network share.

Comment: I didn't down mark you btw, but your suggestion of using DriveInfo requires FileIO Permissions so this would crash my application if it was executed from a network share.

Comment: if you are in "MyComputer" you usually have FileIO Permission... so I think this is more a thing of what is checked first...

Comment: But it wouldnt be in the My_Computer group if the user only has .NET 2.0 installed.

Comment: so then check is to first see what framework version, then what zone... if the zone is not MyComputer then you already know that you running in some "network context"... if it is in MyComputer then you can check with the above method whether this is really local or not